# Program or method to standardize figure format and create multiple, similar figures

Tags: excel, charts, formatting, figure

I couldn't find documentation to help me with this problem - [EDIT: ...and the only recommendations I've gotten from colleagues is what I have mentioned below].

I'm developing 23 figures that must include a PNG image of a state, and two charts with accompanying state data. Each chart has a slightly different scale, though the units will be the same (I say this because it makes formatting a headache). The only way I know how to make these figures is to create a slide in Powerpoint, inserting the charts and PNG and formatting each slide "by hand" to match all the others. This is time consuming and aggravating, and I'm optimistic there's a better way.

#### Question: What program/methods do you recommend for creating a standard figure format?

Ideally I would like to copy-and-paste charts from Excel, and insert a PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into R to do this. Not sure what the PNG image is, but you can use R also to plot data on maps (using heatmaps or otherwise) if you would want to. You can import an image so you can also work with your PNG image if needed.

As for the charts you then could create them using R instead of excel and put everything together.

This way you can write a piece of code once and generate all the figures you need.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris - I think you're right. I'm sure there are options out there to use Python as well, though I haven't discovered them yet. Thanks for input!